# Use external XML file and building the view of the android application

Tags: java, android, xml

I don't know what to call it, but I have only one xml in the application, which allows me to connect to the driver, and when I connect to it, I download the xml files from it and build the application view.
Is such an operation possible? After downloading the XML file, how can I make this file my main application view?
I would like to point out that the xml file is as used in android studio, it is no different.
(I need it because the view is supposed to be driver dependent, which are many kinds and there are constantly xml updates, so I don't know what it will be.)

In short i have an external android xml file, i download it and want to make my application use it like "its" xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Android compiles the xml files at compile time. It creates entries inside R.java. It is not possible to load the xml layout directly from server.

You need to manually parse the xml and need to create view dynamically.
Here is a tutorial for creating dynamic layouts.

https://medium.com/mindorks/creating-dynamic-layouts-in-android-d4008b72f2d